# ¿Cómo borrar dos objetos a la vez en Django Python?

Tags: python, django

Mi problema es que quiero borrar dos objetos a la vez en django pero no se como realizar eso en la url.

**View**

```
    alumno = Alumno.objects.get(id=id_alumno)
    apoderado = Apoderado.objects.get(id=id_apoderado)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        alumno.delete()
        apoderado.delete()
        return redirect('listar_alumnos')
    return render(request, "eliminar_alumno.html", {'alumno':alumno, 'apoderado':apoderado})
```

**URL:** La url intente realizándolo de esa manera pero no me ha funcionado.

```
path('eliminar_alumno/<int:id_alumno>/<int:id_apoderado>', eliminar_alumno, name="eliminar_alumnos")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo que sale en tu URL, deseas eliminar un alumno, con su respectivo apoderado, ambos deben de estar conectados a través de un atributo, por ejemplo:

Un apoderado además de tener sus atributos propios tiene la conexión con alumno, podría ser el id del alumno asociado.

Entonces en tu URL, solo deberías preguntar por solo apoderado:

```py
    url(r'^eliminar/(?P<id_apoderado>\d+)/$', eliminarApoderado, name='eliminar_apoderado'),
```

Tomando el id del apoderado, en la URL, después en la VIEW se tendría que buscar por el alumno asociado primero y luego eliminar, ya sea alumno como el apoderado:

```py
#función para eliminar un alumno
def eliminarAlumno(alumno):
    alumno = User.objects.get(id_alumno = alumno.id_alumno)
    #encuentra el alumno y lo elimina
    alumno.delete()

#Elimina el apoderado, junto al alumno asociado
def eliminarApoderadoAlumno(request, id_apoderado):
    #Se obtiene el objeto que tenga el mismo id que el del apoderado
    apoderado = Apoderado.objects.get(id_apoderado = id_apoderado)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Se elimina el usuario
        eliminarAlumno(apoderado.alumno)
        # Se elimina la ficha
        apoderado.delete()
        #Redirigir a la url que se le indique
        return redirect('lista_apoderados')
    #Envía el registro de apoderados
    return render(request, 'eliminarapoderado.html', {'apoderado':apoderado})
```

---

He creado primero una función que solo se encarga de encontrar el alumno que recibe por parámetro, y lo elimina.

Posteriormente, he creado la vista de `eliminarApoderadoAlumno()`, la cual recibe el parámetro de `id_apoderado`, que le envía la URL.

1. Busca el apoderado que tenga el mismo id y lo trae  a la variable `apoderado`
2. Si el `request`, es `POST`, entonces manda a llamar la función `eliminarAlumno()` y posteriormente elimina el objeto apoderado
3. Redireccionará a donde le indiques

Comment: Oh gracias amigo me sirvio mucho.